# Alternative to /Users/MyUsername/Pictures/pic.jpg

Tags: macos

I'm trying to show a picture in a image well in my mac app. I have managed to show a picture by using:

```
/Users/MyUsername/Pictures/pic.jpg
```

But I need something to replace MyUsername with so that it works for people with different usernames too.

Comment: just a guess (as I'm not confident with osx), does `/Users/$USER/Pictures/pic.jpg` work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the user home directory programatically. This can be done using methods of [NSFileManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/URLForDirectory%3ainDomain%3aappropriateForURL%3acreate%3aerror%3a)

e.g.

```
NSURL* pictureDir = [NSFileManager URLForDirectory:NSUserDirectory 
        inDomain: NSLocalDomainMask 
        appropriateForURL:@"Pictures "
        create:YES
        error:nil];
```